# What are all the quantum equations to find the wave equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, big-list

What are all the quantum equations relativistic and non-relativistic to find the wave equation?
Is it possible to write the name of each equation and its formula, and if it is possible to explain it?

Is it possible to make this question on a community wiki?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/721045/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic hmmm, I'm confused, I don't know, what's wrong with the question? Can you explain?! I have deleted the previous question.

Comment: Hi Mamoun Ghazali. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic , Well I'm still new here, but I deleted the previous question, anyway, what's wrong with this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic , The previous question was: What are all the quantum wave equations? It was wrong and the answer would be long, but I edited the question.

Comment: Same problem : it's a question that would produce only lists of responses, none of them could be definitive or complete and it's therefore an open-ended question.  These are off-topic almost everywhere on the SE site.  In particular there is no way for the community to vote on a "best" answer because there is no "best" answer.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine ,  No problem, I'm new here, but you can look at these questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1319/268718 & https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/268718

Answer (score 0):

**--- Non-relativistic equations:**

1- Schrodinger time-dependent equ.

2- Schrodinger time-independent equ.

3- Schrodinger position-dependent mass equ.

4- Feinberg-Horodecki equ.

**--- Relativistic equation:**

1- Klein-Gorden equ.

2- Dirac equ.

3- duffin-kemmer-petiau equ.